# What does the term "Implementation Defined Standard" mean?

Tags: php

I came across this term while studying a pdf relating to "Dynamic Websites". I tried searching for this term in Google but no luck. Never got any result where i found this exact term.

Also, why it can be problematic?

Comment: What context was it written? I'm guessing there is a defined standard (a de-facto rule) within the implementation of either the code or application. For example, a [naming convention of variables.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196416/whats-the-dominant-naming-convention-for-variables-in-php-camelcase-or-undersc)

Comment: Might help to see where you saw this, but to me its pretty self explanatory.  Its a standard, defined by the implementation, i.e. a project which defines a standard to be used within said project.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI'm actually going through past examination papers for "Dynamic Websites". And saw that question there.

Comment: Essentially it means that implementation defines some standard. The definition is implicit (in a form "whatever implementation does is a standard") rather than explicit ("here's the document that describes our standard")